# Cannot read property 'click' of undefined for an element in protractor

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

I have written a function for log in application using protractor.

```
this.login = function(userName, password){
    return this.emailAddressInput.sendKeys(userName).then(function(){
        return this.nextButton.click().then(function(){
            return this.passwordInput.sendKeys(password).then(function(){
                 this.tibcoLoginButton.click().then(function(){
                     return require('./tce.apps.js') 
                 })

            })
        })
```

I am invoking the function in one of my spec file.

But the error I am getting is:

> Failed: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined.

This if for the nextbutton. Why this is happening?

Comment: `this` is not what you think it is.

Comment: sorry..i did not get..??

Comment: `console.log(this, this.nextButton)` The function is changing it. Basic concept of closures.

Comment: yes, yes i got it. Is there a way to handle this.?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
this.login = function(userName, password){
    var self = this;
    return self.emailAddressInput.sendKeys(userName).then(function(){
        return self.nextButton.click().then(function(){
            return self.passwordInput.sendKeys(password).then(function(){
                 return self.tibcoLoginButton.click().then(function(){
                     return require('./tce.apps.js') 
                 })
            })
        })
    })
}
```

And it's unnecessary to use nested `then()`, but do as following to make more readable.

```
this.login = function(userName, password) {
  var self = this;
  self.emailAddressInput.sendKeys(userName);
  self.nextButton.click();
  self.passwordInput.sendKeys(password);

  return self.tibcoLoginButton.click().then(function() {
    return require('./tce.apps.js')
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.nextButton` is undefined because 'this', being lexically inside a `.then` method, is referring to a Promise object.

Comment: Yes.I got it now. Is there a way to handle this.?

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to use **then** function to write login function. You can try create LoginPage Object page, following this:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

this.getUserInput = function () {
        return user_input;
    };
this.getPasswordInput = function () {
        return password_input;
    };
this.setUserInput = function (text) {
        user_input.clear().sendKeys(text);
    };
this.setPasswordInput = function (text) {
        password_input.clear().sendKeys(text);
    };
this.getLoginButton = function () {
        return login_button;
    };
    this.clickLogin = function () {
        login_button.click();
    };
this.login = function(username, password) {
    browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(this.getUserInput()));
    browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(this.getPasswordInput()));
    this.getUserInput().click();
    this.setUserInput(username);
    this.getPasswordInput().click();
    this.setPasswordInput(password);
    browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(this.getLoginButton()));
    this.clickLogin();
  };
```